# Why are new guest users able to view the tenant management portal and invite users in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I've been evaluating Azure Active Directory B2C as a solution for an identity provider I need for an upcoming project.

During my evaluation I noticed the following behavior that I am not sure should be possible:

I am in my B2C tenant and I invite a new guest user. In this case it is for a different email address that I control. This email address has no association to this B2C instance nor the parent AD instance, the Azure account or anything related. It is a throw away account I am using for testing.

I get the invitation sent to that address and log in through a different browser in incognito mode. I create my account and complete that flow.

**Now here is where I am slightly concerned with security:**

Logged in as this user I am able to do the following:

- Log into the B2C instance and see some top level info such as the TenantId, etc...
- I do not see other users BUT I can click on the "New Guest User" button ("New User" is greyed out) and can attempt to create/invite users. I am blocked from all the operations I tried but it seems strange to surface this UI.
- Even though it said the operation was blocked my invitation to another email address I control actually went through. I was able to go through the invitation flow. There were some errors and it even said the invitation code was not valid... but despite this the invitation completed and I was able to log into the tenant management UI with this new user.
- This user was also able to create invitations.
- I also see this new user that was invited by the guest in my user list logged in as the account admin.

**So my questions are:**

- Is this by design? Why?
- Is this a possible bug?
- Can this be blocked?
- Why can B2C guest users invite other users and initiate the flow?
- Why can B2C guest users even log into the tenant management site?

I can't imagine why a default scenario would allow new users that have not been given any privileges to view your tenant and invite other guests. In my scenario this should not be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of guest users in B2C is to invite other people who can be admins.

These people are not local users.

If you want to invite people to be local users, use a [magic link](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite).

Comment: Oh, so neither of these are the actual "Consumers" - these are both tenant managers? Where would the list of the actual consumers be once populated?

Comment: You'll find them under "Users" in the tenant This list contains both admin and local and social (federated).